# java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException error in JAR not in IDE

Tags: java, jar, rsa, public-key

I wrote a RSA encryption code which worked fine on IDE but after making JAR file it gave error - `java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException`

```
private static PublicKey readPubKey()throws Exception{
    //reading public key from the path specified in the configuration file
    Config conf = new Config();
    InputStream keyfis = conf.getFileInputStream(publicKeyPath);
    byte[] encKey = new byte[keyfis.available()];
    keyfis.read(encKey);
    keyfis.close();

    // making the instance of Public key from the bytes of the Public Key
    X509EncodedKeySpec pubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encKey);
    java.security.KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

    //---------------problem in this line of code-----------
    PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
    return publicKey;
}
```

The problem is in line -

```
PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
```

Full Stack Trace of Exception is -

```
Exception Caught : java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: 
java.security.InvalidKeyException: exponent is smaller than 3
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: 
java.security.InvalidKeyException: exponent is smaller than 3
at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:205)
at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:334)
at com.token.TokenVerifier.readPubKey(TokenVerifier.java:55)
at com.token.TokenVerifier.verify(TokenVerifier.java:77)
at com.test.Main.main(Main.java:28)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: exponent is smaller than 3
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl.checkExponentRange(RSAPublicKeyImpl.java:99)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl.<init>(RSAPublicKeyImpl.java:88)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.generatePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:298)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:201)
```

Comment: Perhaps the file contents have been corrupted or are otherwise incorrect. Also, the code you are using to read the data from the file is *not* reliable. You cannot assume that `read(...)` will read in all the bytes in one call, that's why it returns an integer count of the number of bytes read. You need to use something like `DataInputStream.readFully()`, `Files.readAllBytes()`, or similar methods from Google Guava or Apache commons-io.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to convert inputstream to byte array.

```
InputStream keyfis = conf.getFileInputStream(publicKeyPath);
byte[] encKey = toByteArray(keyfis);
keyfis .close();

public static byte[] toByteArray(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    // read bytes from the input stream and store them in buffer
    while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        // write bytes from the buffer into output stream
        os.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    return os.toByteArray();
}
```

Please refer to the below url. Thanks to the author of the below url for the utility method - toByteArray.

https://www.techiedelight.com/convert-inputstream-byte-array-java/

If you are verifying signature in the same program, use the same method to convert to byte array before verifying the signature, else it will give an error there also.

Comment: Most of your code here looks identical to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54204099/12695027), or perhaps [this source](https://www.techiedelight.com/convert-inputstream-byte-array-java/). Kindly read [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). If you found the code and adapted it from somewhere else, please clearly indicate that in your answer.