# Project works in eclipse but not after being packaged in a jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, itext7

My project uses itext7 to create PDF files.  When I launch from eclipse everything works perfectly.  When I package it as a jar, everything works until I get to the point that I want to create a PDF.  I then get:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" com.itextpdf.io.IOException: I/O exception.
>       .....
>
> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\puser\eclipse-workspace\Document\target\SE001-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\img\Safety.png (The system cannot find the path specified)

The project folder keeps the images at `src/main/resources/img`.  Once the jar is created it simply has `/img` at root.  This means you can't just specify a direct path because it changes when the jar is made.  JavaFX Images work fine with..

```
Image user = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/img/Document.png"));
```

Using that with itext7 doesn't work because `ImageDataFactory.create()` is looking for byte[] and that is an input stream.

Now trying to use:

```
Image safetyImage = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/img/Safety.png"));
```

Does not work because the Jar is not inside the path.

What can I use to point to an image file inside the jar and use it with it ext7?

Comment: *"Using that with itext7 doesn't work because ImageDataFactory.create() is looking for byte[] and that is an input stream."* - how about using a utility method that reads an inputstream into a byte array? There are numerous such utilities floating around, itext contains one, too.

Comment: Why can't you put the `/img/Safety.png` also inside the resource folder?

Comment: The resource folder only exists when it is a maven project.  That is document root at that time.  When it is a jar document root is /.  In other words, Safety.png is in the resource folder along with all the other images.  I think mkl is right about using a utility method to read an inputstream and then convert that into a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

mkl was correct and thank you!

I created a utility method to convert an input steam to a byte array.

```
   public static byte[] toByteArray(InputStream in) throws IOException {
          //InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(System.in);
          ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];
          int len;
          // read bytes from the input stream and store them in buffer
            while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                // write bytes from the buffer into output stream
                os.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            return os.toByteArray();
       }
```

I then used that utility inside the ImageDataFactory.create() method.

```
Image safetyImage = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(toByteArray(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/img/Safety.png"))));
```